# WM_PAINT and MOUSE Event. MFC/WIN32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

i have two rectangle in my WM_PAINT and i wanted to draw Frame Rect on it once WM_MOUSE CLICK EVENT is triggered  that toggle on each rectangle. is this even possible?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. A it stands here it is totally unclear and too broad.

Comment: You need to have your mouse click handler save which rectangle is being clicked on, and then invalidate the window so a new `WM_PAINT` is triggered, so it can then draw a frame around the clicked rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @RemyLebeau's comment above regarding your mouse clicks.  Then, in your WndProc, something like:

```
switch (uMsg)
{
    // ...

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PaintStruct ps;
        HDC hDC = BeginPaint (hWnd, &ps);
        HBRUSH hBrush = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (LTGRAY_BRUSH);   // say
        if (draw_first_rectangle)
            FrameRect (hDC, &my_first_rectangle, hBrush);
        if (draw_second_rectangle)
            FrameRect (hDC, &my_second_rectangle, hBrush);
        EndPaint (hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    // ...

}

return DefWindowProc (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

I'm sure you can fill in the blanks.

Comment: Hmm right but this mean i need to invalidate  in order to proc the WM_PAINT message everytime i Receive the WM_MOUSECLICK message right? If this the case this will cause flickering each time i click on my rectangle.

Comment: Ah well, flickering.  That's a whole other issue.  See if it's really a problem for you, and if so please ask a new question.

Comment: And [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.  I did actually post something about writing a flicker-free WM_PAINT handler, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656524/5743288.  In addition to what it says there, you have to set your class background brush to `GetStockObject (NULL_BRUSH)` and draw the entire window - background and all - in your `WM_PAINT` handler.  You might start by filling the hDC with (say) a WHITE_BRUSH and then draw your rectangles and whetever else.  Then, when you call `EndBufferedPaint ()`, it all gets blasted to the screen in a single operation, so no flicker.

Comment: But this is all just in passing.  If you want to get a proper answer about this, please post a new question.